# Single extension for UITextView and UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, swift-extensions

I want to create a single **extension** for both `UITextField` and `UITextView` and add a below method to it:

```
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboardWith(selector : Selector)
    {
        let keyBoardToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 30))
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: selector)
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        keyBoardToolBar.items = [flexibleSpace, barButtonItem]
        keyBoardToolBar.barStyle = .default
        self.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar
        self.reloadInputViews()
    }
```

I want the extension method to be available only for `UITextField` and `UITextView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work, since `UIView` is the parent class of them, downside is probably this will appear on all kinds of view, not sure if there's any other way to achieve what you need:

```
extension UIView  {
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboardWith(selector : Selector)
    {
        if self is UITextField || self is UITextView {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case addDoneButtonOnKeyboardWith() method will be available on other UIView types as well, i.e. UIButton, UILabel etc.

Comment: I already mention it as the downside? Also interested to see other solution though

Answer (score 4):

I have an idea that could do what you want, utilising the default implementation of a protocol. *Technically* you would still need two extensions but they would both be totally empty. Consider the following:

Create a protocol for your method, and provide a default implementation:

```
protocol DoneButtonBearer {
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboardWith(selector: Selector)
}

extension DoneButtonBearer {
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboardWith(selector: Selector) {
        var view: UIView?
        defer  {
            if view != nil {
                let keyBoardToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 30))
                let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: selector)
                let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
                keyBoardToolBar.items = [flexibleSpace, barButtonItem]
                keyBoardToolBar.barStyle = .default
                view!.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar
                view!.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }
        if let textField = self as? UITextField {
            view = textField
            return
        }
        if let textView = self as? UITextView {
            view = textView
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Then just extend `UITextField` and `UITextView` with this functionality:

`extension UITextField: DoneButtonBearer { }`

`extension UITextView: DoneButtonBearer { }`

Answer (score 0):

The closest class, which you can extend is UIControl, you can extend it but this method will be accessible again for UIButtons and other controls.

So you can extend or subclass for example UIBarButtonItem with static method.

```swift
class func addDoneBarButtonOnKeyboardFor(keyInput: UIControl <UIKeyInput>, usingSelector : Selector)
{
    let keyBoardToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 30))
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: selector)
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    keyBoardToolBar.items = [flexibleSpace, barButtonItem]
    keyBoardToolBar.barStyle = .default
    keyInput.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar
    keyInput.reloadInputViews()
}
```

Sorry if made some mistake in Swift code. Developing on Obj C now.