# Single extension for TextView and TextField to add a toolBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to create a single extension to add a toolBar on a keyboard for TextView and TextField.

For now I’m doing that on both TextView and TextField:

```
extension UITextView {
func setKeyboardToolBar(items: [UIBarButtonItem]) {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 44.0))
    toolBar.setItems(items, animated: false)
    self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

}

But it’s annoying to have the exact same function in 2 different extensions.

I tried to extend UIView like in this question [Single extension for UITextView and UITextField in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738258/single-extension-for-uitextview-and-uitextfield-in-swift) but I got an error with inputAccessoryView because it's a get only property.

How could I factorise these two same functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
extension UITextField: KeyboardToolbarCompatible {}
extension UITextView: KeyboardToolbarCompatible {}

protocol KeyboardToolbarCompatible: AnyObject {
    func setKeyboardToolBar(items: [UIBarButtonItem])
    var inputAccessoryView: UIView? { get set }
}

extension KeyboardToolbarCompatible {
    func setKeyboardToolBar(items: [UIBarButtonItem]) {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 44.0))
        toolBar.setItems(items, animated: false)
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
}
```

If this is needed only for TextView and TextField then KeyboardToolbarCompatible can confirm to UITextInput.

```
protocol KeyboardToolbarCompatible: UITextInput { ... }
```